# Suprema and Infima of subsets of $\mathbb R$. 

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Real Analysis Question (Suprema, Infima and $\mathbb R$)

Question:

> Suppose $U$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$, bounded above, with supremum $s$. If $a$ is any number satisfying $a < s$, explain why there is some $u\in U$ with $a < u$.

Please can someone help with this question?

Comment: Perhaps if you write out the definition of "supremum" all will become clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If the set $U$ had no element $>a$, then $a$ would be an upper bound for $U$.

Answer (score 0):

If not, then $u \leq a$ for all $u\in U$, but this shows that $a$ is the sup, contridiction.

Comment: That doesn’t show that $a=\sup U$: it shows that $a$ is **an** upper bound for $U$, but not necessarily the smallest one. However, that’s enough to get a contradiction.